# how to iterate two arrays in foreach loop to get single record

Tags: php

I have two arrays one is associative and second one is non associative i want to insert for each item of each array as a row  in the database. In my code below $menu and $id are array . This $id part is giving me error as this itself is an array  .... error says "array to string conversion".  Please help!!!

```
foreach($menu as $label => $link) {
    $id = $request->themeLocation;
    DB::table('menus')->insertGetId([ 'label' => $label ,'url' => $link ,'themeLocation' => '$id ,'menu_status' => 1  ]); 
}
```

after applying foreach with in foreach i am  geting hierarchy entries in DB

```
   id   themeLocation   url label   menu_status

       41   child-38    about   ABOUT US    1
       42   child-39    about   ABOUT US    1
       43   child-40    about   ABOUT US    1
       44   child-38    services    Services    1
       45   child-39    services    Services    1
       46   child-40    services    Services    1
       47   child-38    contact contact 1
       48   child-39    contact contact 1
       49   child-40    contact contact 1
```

but i am getting redundant entries in DB i want this result

```
       41   child-38    about   ABOUT US    1
       42   child-39    services    Services    1
       43   child-40    contact contact 1
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: The syntax highlighting probably solves your problem?

Comment: You have an extra quote before `$id`.

Comment: Thanks  but how   ???

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error was because you had an extra quote in `=> '$id`.

If `$id` is an array, you need a nested loop to insert every value. You should get the array outside the `$menu` loop, since it's not dependent on anything in that array.

```
$locations = $request->themeLocation;
foreach ($menu as $label => $link) {
    foreach ($locations as $loc) {
        DB::table('menus')->insertGetId([
            'label' => $label ,
            'url' => $link ,
            'themeLocation' => $loc,
            'menu_status' => 1  ]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what that's supposed to mean.